# Can't navigate to a domain subpath of another server in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router-v4, create-react-app

I meet an issue as below:

- My react-app is hosted at https://myserver.com and
- Another server is hosted at https://myserver.com/another-server

I want to navigate outside React so I tried with window.location = 'https://myserver.com/another-server' in my React app code. It works with development mode (I uses create-react-app) but does not work with production mode. My react-app grabbed that URL and rendered to NotFound component in my router.

Production mode built by using:

- npm run build
- serve -s build

I doubt this is caused by serviceWorker but any ideas?